# Open WRL file (VRML) from .NET

Tags: vb.net, vrml

For some reason, I would display vrml model from my VB.net dialog, does anyone has ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I gave up using VRML and used Helix toolkit with opening OBJ file.